Movie based on a father's eulogy for his daughter based in early twentieth century
I think it was based on a father's actual eulogy or essay about his dead daughter. It covered the last few weeks/month of her life, before she left home(for school?). 
The daughter had black hair and was in her late teens/early twenties. It came out in the mid to late 70s to early 80s. She was killed when s horse she was riding threw her into a tree and broke her neck, or something similar. Her face is shown smashing into the tree. 
This was a U.S. Movie, and is set somewhere in the states. The actress had thick dark hair and huge dark eyes. I think she may have been in only a couple of other movies. 
I saw the movie on t.v.

The movie is Mary White, and it is from 1977. It was based on a true story about a girl that was killed in a horse riding accident in the early 1900's.!


Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.
